# Eclipse erased all java files after manually moving projects from workspace

Tags: android, eclipse, project, workspace

Since the workspace is a little bit messy, I have created a new folder in windows and manually move the projects in the original workspace to the new folder.

Afterwards, I import all the project to the Eclipse, but the projects all fail. I go back to the folder and to my surprise, all the java documents become blank.

Does anyone know what is going on???

Comment: You lost all the references in your WorkSpace! OK... try doing so: File/Switch WorkSpace/Other and choose your new path. Good luck

Comment: I viewed back the java documents in Windows folder and it opens with Internet Explorer, inside all gone ...Eclipse should not have erased all the things itself when it clean up projects?!

Comment: now all Parser exception for /abc_app/AndroidManifest.xml: Premature end of file.

Comment: is there a way to open an apk to retrieve the codes? I have the key and the password!

Comment: Well **this is not perfectly legal**, you must know it. Even if you bought the app, you are not the owner ot its copyrights. It is up to you, then, to decide if you really want to **STUDY** how it is done, **for learning purposes**...

Comment: thanks for your guides...! I am retrieving my own things =) But how come others' codes can be retrieved using these means...without keys and passwords...odd...